# Rotating frames

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

A bird of mass $m$ is on a merry-go-round of radius $a$ which rotates at constant angular velocity $-\omega_b$ in the $y$ direction. A woman of mass $M$ is on a second merry-go-around of radius $b$ which rotates at constant angular velocity $\omega_s$ in the $z$ direction around the same origin. At $t=0$ the bird is at $(a,0,0)$ and the woman at $(b,0,0)$. What is the force of friction acting on the bird as seen by the woman?

Comment: Well, I have tried converting the axes from the inertial to the rotating reference frame of the bird and then tried writing the centrifugal force acting on the bird at that frame while the woman is at rest. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: What are the y and z directions?  Are a and b the radii of the merry-go-rounds, or the positions of the participants on the rides?

Comment: The standard axes are used. The question was not supplemented with a diagram. a and b are both the radii and initial positions, as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you move from an inertial frame to one non-inertial frame and then to another, you need to invoke various fictitious forces to continue to misapply Newton's Laws to situations where you can't use them. For example, a passenger in a car going around a curve to the left may choose to consider himself as a frame of reference, and explains his constant zero velocity in that frame as the result of the force of the door on his right side and the fictitious centrifugal force towards the right adding to zero.

But, **all observers will agree on the size of any real forces** that exist in the system.  Suppose the bird in the question was held in place by a radial spring, rather than friction;  would different observers see different spring constants, or different spring extensions?

So, with respect to the bird and the friction between its feet and the surface of the merry-go-round, just use the inertial observer $$F_f=m\omega_b^2a$$